# Need help to take height from browser width for a bootstrap div

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, width

I am developing a HTMl page with bootstrap 3. I am using below codes for showing an flipping image. In smartphone screen I want to keep the height of id card-1 same as the width of the window.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card" id="card-1"> 
        <div class="front"> 
            <img src="img/p1.jpg" alt="Portfolio Images" class="img-responsive">
        </div> 
        <div class="back">
            <img src="img/hover.png" alt="Portfolio Images" class="img-responsive">
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

How may I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qjb2wvkj/2/)

You can get the width of the window with: `$(window).width();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    $('#card-1').height(w);
});
```

You can update it with an onchange or something like that. But i don't think that is necessary.